# Using typescript transforms I want to find and replace the this keyword, how do I find it?

Tags: typescript

Using https://astexplorer.net/ I can see that the type of this is a type of expression called a "ThisKeyword". However looking at the typescript API I can't find either a KeywordKind or a isThisKeyword style function that I can use to determine that a particular expression is a ThisKeyword.

How am I supposed to determine if a given node is a ThisKeyword node?

[image: Highlighted this keyword in code on the left shows an expression:ThisKeyword AST Node with kind 104 in a panel on the right.]

Comment: I would guess that this is encoded in the `kind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was encoded in the `kind` as @H.B. suggested (and I had a suspicion of as well), but to not all nodes have a kind (only expressions do) and there is no `ts.isExpression` helper function. I also didn't know where the this node's kind was located (as ts provides many different groups of kinds), turns out it's a `ts.SyntaxKind`.

I ended up testing the parent node using `ts.isPropertyAccessExpression` and then checking if the child's kind is `ts.SyntaxKind.ThisType` or `ts.SyntaxKind.ThisKeyword` (the second one being the one that I expected to work, but the first one having the value 104 which was listed above in the ast explorer).

This works for my purposes, I don't know if there are any limitations to this approach though.